# Cannot find module 'react' from 'pure.js'?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

When running `yarn test` in `package.json` which is

`CI=true react-app-rewired test --coverage`

I got following error

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react' from 'pure.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './pure.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:28:37)
```

Not sure why getting `react` from `pure.js`, any idea?

Comment: Have you checked that React is installed? Try installing with npm i react and running again. If it works, react wasn't installed properly in the first place.

Comment: @AJarofClay, I figured out that the project has 2 package.jsons top level dir and inner level dir . So need to stick to inner level dir to do dev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' from 'node\_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713405/cannot-find-module-react-dom-client-from-node-modules-testing-library-react)

Answer (score 13):

I was also facing the same issue, then I installed `"react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"` and the issue is resolved.
So you can try this also just installed this dependency by command **`npm install react-test-renderer --save`**.

**As you can see in the below image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jest is unable to find `'react'` because it is either not installed or the closest `package.json` does not have react as a dependency (if it's a monorepo).

Answer (score 0):

##### It's related to Version of @testing-library/react not being compatible with your react version

as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71716438/8667766)

> I think it's because your using the newer version of @testing-library/react , just try installing version 12.1.2 (or 12.x)

[quote edited by me]

And as [Kalm mentioned here too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68472473/8667766)

if it's a mono repo project, you have to take care of every package.json file.

in my case(in a monorepo project), someone has installed a higher version of `@testing-library/react` which will not work with my current `react` version, so the solution was to trace every `package.json` and check what version of `@testing-library/react` I was using, then make sure it's using a lower version