# Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing

While running `npm test` I got following error:

```
Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js'
Required stack:
node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js
node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/index.js
```

All necessary packages seem to be installed. I reinstalled `react-dom`, but it didn't help. Below providing imports used in my test file:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Additionally providing my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "fe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.0",
    "@mui/material": "5.5.3",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.5.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.28.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.25",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.24",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.4.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I think it's because your @testing-library/react using the newer version, just test with version of 12.1.2

Comment: npm i -D @testing-library/react@12.1.2

Comment: The reason is, `@testing-library/react` v13+ doesn't support React <=17.
So, for `React` >=18 -> `@testing-library/react` >=13+
and for `React` <=17 -> `@testing-library/react` <=12.1.5

Comment: Since latest 12.x version has changed since this answer, the `release-12.x` can be used: `npm i -D @testing-library/react@release-12.x`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved my whole career with this. My project wasn't running and I couldn't figure out why until I came across this. Thank you, man.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that 12.1.2 doesn't include `renderHook`

Comment: I also faced the same issue while using react 16 and `@testing-library/react version` 14.1.2. Issue resolved after using `@testing-library/react` version 12.x.

Answer (score 68):

According to [@testing-library/react release notes](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v13.0.0), `version 13` (and above) has **dropped support** for `React 17` and bellow. So using this library with `React <= 17` will cause this error (or maybe others).

You can downgrade to any version of `@testing-library/react` bellow 13 to fix it.
At the time of this writing the latest would be `12.1.5` which works fine with `React 17`.

Another option is to upgrade React to 18 and above.

Answer (score 9):

I was also getting the error "Cannot find module 'react-dom/client'" without mention of @testing-library/react.

Looks like the syntax to hook up the react-redux Provider has changed here:
https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started
(in the code block where it mentions "// As of React 18").

To get this to work I had to make sure I was on version 18 or above for react and react-dom, and updated all other client npm packages too. Many needed to be updated with:

```bash
npm update package-name --legacy-peer-deps
```

Took me a few hours to figure this out. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I am working on a new react project with typescript + vite, but what I found out was some of my dependencies were outdated, then I follow this steps to resolve this issue.

1. List item
2. I deleted my node_module
3. I run npm install
4. Then I run `npm update --force`
5. Then I install the lates types/react-dom  and types/react by running  `npm install --save-dev @types/react-dom@latest    @types/react@latest` in the terminal