# React App: Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, bit.dev

I'm currently experiencing this error and I'm not really sure how to fix it. I've been trying to merge a project with components stored in bit.dev.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'; // Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' or its corresponding type declarations.
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
if (!rootElement) throw new Error('Failed to find the root element');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Here is the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' from 'node\_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713405/cannot-find-module-react-dom-client-from-node-modules-testing-library-react)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone that might experience the same problem, the version of react bit.dev is using and the version the actual app is using are different. All I had to do was change the way the app was rendered (in this case react v17).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

After running `npm install react react-dom` or `yarn add react react-dom` as instructed [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html), you should then run

```
npm install -D @types/react-dom
```

or

```
yarn add -D @types/react-dom
```

This will add `react-dom/client` type declarations to your project and will remove the error you pointed at on line 2 of your code.

Comment: Of course, they were already installed. Yet it continues to show that error for `react-dom/client`.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

Then `ReactDOM.createRoot`

Comment: It gives the same error/warning.