# Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in React 17 while using React 18 library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-18

After the release of React V18 on 29th March, we upgraded our library to be React v18 compatible, but now the library is no more compatible to be used under React V17 or React v16.

It gives the below error during consumption:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in '.../node_modules/library/dist...'
```

What will be the right approach to create a forward and backward compatible React package?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713405/cannot-find-module-react-dom-client-from-node-modules-testing-library-react.

Comment: @karoluS nope this is not what I am asking, Upgrading to React V18 is a known solution, but I want my library to be working on both React V17 and V18, if you know any idea on how to do it?

Comment: If the library that you are using need a React 18. You cannot use it with react 17. You need to downgrade the version of the library to match your React version.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to import react-dom/client? A library should not use createRoot since it should be used in an application.

If you want to render something in a container provided by the application, try createPortal instead. It should be available in both React v17 and v18.